# UIImageView Blend Mode Multiply over moving UIView

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Is it possible to overlay a `UIImageView` with a `multiply` blend mode if the view beneath it is not static? I have a texture I'd like to overlay my app with.

Comment: Have you got solution?